# android - access base activity from custom layout

Tags: android, layout, fragment

I have a custom layout in my fragment , which extends RelativeLayout

```
    public class Footer extends RelativeLayout
```

How can i use getSupportFragmentManager from this custom object ? When i use this.getContext() it gives Application , not FragmentActivity.

```
  The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Footer (extends RelativeLayout)
```

Waiting for your help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send Context in Constructor like this

Let your Activity be `MyFragmentActivity`

```
MyFragmentActivity activity;
Footer(MyFragmentActivity activity)
{
 this.context=context;
}
```

And From your Activity send Activity name.this

i.e

```
MyFragmentActivity.this
```

And now you can use

```
activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
```